# My LWC (with Emp API implemented) stops receiving Platform Events after some time (6-10 minutes) from the time we opened the page Dev Org

Tags: limits, platform-event, empapi

**-------------- Info ------------**

I have **one LWC**, where I **subscribe** to **Platform Events** using [lightning/empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) .

Here the **JS code** from the LWC :

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, onError, unsubscribe} from 'lightning/empApi';
    
export default class PlatformEventOrderSubscriber extends LightningElement {
    channelName = '/event/Event_Type__e';
    subscription = {};

    connectedCallback() {
        this.registerErrorListener();
        this.handleSubscribe();
    }

    handleSubscribe() {
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (response) => this.messageCallbackProcessor(response)).then(response => {
                this.subscription = response;
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
    
    messageCallbackProcessor(response) {
        // do sommething
    }

    registerErrorListener() {
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            if( error 
                    && error.hasOwnProperty('advice') && error.advice
                    && error.advice.hasOwnProperty('reconnect') && error.advice.reconnect
                    && error.advice.reconnect === 'handshake') 
            {
                this.handleSubscribe();
            }
        });
    }

    disconnectedCallback(){
        unsubscribe(this.subscription, (response) => {
            console.log('unsubscribe() response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
}
```

The logic is **fully tested** and **works** in all cases (except the one bellow)!

**------Issue--------**

**After some time** (6-10 minutes) from the time we **opened the page**, we **stop receiving Platform Events** from Apex ( I fire the events in Custom Object Trigger).
When it stops working we do **NOT** receive any error in console!

this **LWC** is included in **Managed package** .

It happens only in my **Dev Org** where I created the LWC.

And I can not find anything about it in the documentation.

I tried to look into [The CometD Reference Book](https://docs.cometd.org/current3/reference/#_preface), but couldn't find anything about it.

I checked next topics/links/questions :

- [Emp Api LWC documentaion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) - nothing about it.
- [LWC platform events timing out?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335489/lwc-platform-events-timing-out) - similar issue to my, however no answer there !
- [Clients and Timeouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_timeouts.htm) - link from previous question, not sure if it is our case.
- [Streaming API, does salesforce server disconnect client after some time?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224378/streaming-api-does-salesforce-server-disconnect-client-after-some-time) another similar question, and no **good** answer here.

At first I thought it was related to this issue : [Received Error from Platform Event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/356973/i-have-this-error-from-my-lightning-message-channel-in-lwc-what-can-cause-this) .
However **Platform Events** stop working before we receive this issue.

So can it be just **because of bad Internet connection** ?

We are not hitting any limits which described here : [Platform Event Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.html)

I checked it with Postman and we are not even Close to hitting the **Limits**,
Here some of them :

[image]

It still strange that the Max value for **MonthlyPlatformEventsUsageEntitlement** limits is 0.

[image]

We do not have this issue in any other **Developer Organizations**, **Sandboxes** or **Productions**.
However it is better to know why we have this issue ?

**Maybe anyone already deal with something like it ?**

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Take a look at [debug logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_debug.htm). Another way to debug: create another listener, an in-process (on SF platform) listener and see if the "missing" events are delivered to this listener. This could shed more light on whether the issue is consumer side or SF event bus or the path of the event from the bus to your LWC listener.

Comment: @identigral Thanks, the Platform Event goes from another Managed Package, so I can't take a look at debug logs. I will try to create another listener.

Comment: Is anything else going on in your page resp LWC when it stops working? Can you bring everything else to a halt for testing purposes? You're saying you are not seeing any other errors "when" it stops working - do you see any errors _since_ it last worked?

Comment: @FelixvanHove thanks for reaching out.  Good point! 
However I can just open the page, test the Platform Event one time wait 6-10 minutes, there will be no logs and after that Platform Events Stop working.
Still it is a good idea to leave only this component on the page and check if it works, I will try it.